# covariant derivative along a constant curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the Rimannian manifold $(M,g)$, for it's tangent bundle $TM$ we can consider a local curve inside  a coordiante neiborhoof for example $$\gamma(t) = (p(t) = p_0,t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})\subset TM$$
for some $i$.Which is a curve on the fiber.

Then consider $p(t)$ as a constant curve we can take covariant derivative of the vector field $t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ along the curve:

$$D_t (t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + t D_t(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\tag{1}$$ by the product rule correct. But if we do it alternatively :

$$D_t(t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \nabla_{\dot{p}} (t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \nabla_0(t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = 0 \tag{2}$$

From my perspective (1) should be the correct solution (2) is incorrect, but I can't see where goes wrong.

[This  question comes from something about the Sasaki metric on the tangent bundle which is defined to be :

$$\langle V, W\rangle_{(p_0, v_0)}=\langle d \pi(V), d \pi(W)\rangle_{p_0}+\left\langle\frac{D v}{d t}(0), \frac{D w}{d s}(0)\right\rangle_{p_0}$$

For $V,W \in T_{(p_0,v_0)}TM$, with the associate curve $\alpha:t \mapsto (p(t),v(t))$ and $\beta:s\mapsto (q(s),w(s))$ where $p(0) = q(0) = p_0, v(0) = w(0) = v_0$. With $\alpha'(0) = V, \beta'(0) = W$,and $\frac{D v}{d t}$ denote the covariant derivative of $v(t)$ along the curve $\alpha$.

Comment: When $p\ne q$, these curves have no point in common. How do you compute an inner product?

Comment: The expression $D_tX=\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\widetilde{X}$ only make sense when the vector field $X$ along $\gamma$ is (at least locally) the pullback of some vector field $\widetilde{X}$ on $M$. Notice that $t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is not a well defined local vector field on $M$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin , that's not the problem, we consider $V,W \in T_{(p_0,v)}TM$ , so the curve must pass through $(p_0,v)$ at time zero

Comment: @Kajelad  , I was confusing with the definition of the Sasaki metric,if the vector field $V\in T_{(p,v)}TM$ is vertical,the associate curve $(p(t),v(t))$ does not gives a well defined vector field $v(t)$? If so how to compute the covariant derivative $D_t v(t)$ needed for Sasaki metric?

Comment: @yili There are two kinds of vector fields involved: vector fields *along curves*, and vector fields on $M$. Given a curve $\gamma$, every vector field on $M$ pulls back to a vector field along $\gamma$, but not every vector field along $\gamma$ is a pullback. The operator $D_t$ is defined to be equal to $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}$ for pullbacks; it uniquely extended to the rest using the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Please reread your last two sentences!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see the problem,

Note that $t\mapsto \partial_{x^i} \in $ is extenable vector field,while $t\mapsto t\partial_{x^i}$ is not a extenable vector field along the curve $p(t) = p_0$.

So If we compute $$D_t(t \partial_{x^i}) \ne \nabla_{\dot{p}}(t\partial_{x^i})$$.

While the Leibniz rule holds for $D_t$ therefore:

$$D_t(t\partial{x^i}) = \partial x^i + tD_t\partial x^i$$ in this step we can apply $$D_t \partial x^i = \nabla_{\dot{p}}\partial x^i = 0$$

$$D_t(t \partial x^i) = \partial x^i$$.

As a direct consequence of this result we can prove :

> for Sasaki metric the vector field $V$ on the tangent bundle
> $\pi:TM\to M$(with associate cruve $t\mapsto (p(t),v(t))$) is
> horizental if and only if $v(t)$ as a vector field along the curve
> $p(t)$ parallel along the curve $p(t)$.

**Proof** if part can be checked directly, for the only if part.

For horizontal $V$ (with associative curve $t\mapsto (q(t),w(t))$), it means for every $W \in \ker d\pi$, we have $$\tilde{g} (V,W) = 0$$

In particular consider the vector field $W$ induced by the vertical curve $t\mapsto (p_0,t\partial x^i)$ (easy to check $d\pi (W) = 0$) so:

$$\tilde{g}(V,W) = g(d\pi(V),d\pi (W)) + g(D_t w(0),D_t(t\partial x^i)) = g(d\pi(V),0) + g(D_t w(0),\partial x^i) = 0 $$

Since $i$ can be arbitary so $D_t w(0) = 0$, which means $w$ is parallel to the curve $q(t)$.